# Confusion Matrix with image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to work with the FER2013 dataset, but I'm having trouble getting test data (confusion matrix). I downloaded the dataset and read it using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory so I have data in batches. The problem is that I found two methods to build the confusion matrix, each one gives me a different output and I don't know which method is correct and why the other one is wrong.

In the first method I accumulate all the X's and Y in X_test_complete and Y_test_complete arrays, to then assemble my confusion matrix using Y_total and Y_pred_total. This is the code:

```
test_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        test_directory,
        image_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        seed=42,
        color_mode="grayscale"
)

x_test_complete = np.concatenate([x for x, y in test_data], axis=0)
y_test_complete = np.concatenate([y for x, y in test_data], axis=0)
y_test_complete = to_categorical(y_test_complete, num_classes=7)
y_test_complete_pred = model.predict(x_test_complete, verbose=0)

cm = confusion_matrix(
        np.argmax(y_test_complete, axis=1), 
        np.argmax(y_test_complete_pred, axis=1), 
        labels=range(7)
)
```

In the second method I accumulate the results of the confusion matrix from each batch:

```
test_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        test_directory,
        image_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        seed=42,
        color_mode="grayscale"
)

conf_matrix = np.zeros((7, 7))

for batch in test_data.as_numpy_iterator():
        x_test, y_test = batch
        y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=7)
        y_test_pred = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)

        batch_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(
                np.argmax(y_test, axis=1),
                np.argmax(y_test_pred, axis=1),
                labels=range(7)
        )
        conf_matrix += batch_confusion_matrix
```

In the same execution (same model, same parameters) I got two very different outputs:

**Method 1:**
[Confusion Matrix using first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL83a.png)

**Method 2:**
[Confusion Matrix using second method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhjJR.png)

Which method is correct and why? Or are none of them correct, and if so, how should I do this?

Comment: I started to believe that when using np.concatenate the relation between X and Y is getting out of order, making the prediction rely on luck (and therefore the accuracy is always close to 15%). If so, how do I fix it?